# Problem with overwriting diagram files using feynmf.sty

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu, feynmf

I've just installed `feynmf.sty` from the software center and tried working with a standard example,

```
\begin{fmffile}{simple} % simple.mf will be created for this feynman diagram 
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25) % define diagram size
\fmfleft{i1,i2} % define left inputs
\fmfright{o1,o2} % define right outputs
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1} % define 'arrow' lines through input nr 1 -- vortex nr 1 -- output nr 1
\fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2} % define 'arrow' lines through input nr 2 -- vortex nr 2 -- output nr 2
%\fmf{photon}{v1,v2} % define 'snake' line linked vortices
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
```

(Found on http://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Feynman_diagrams .)

The compilation worked fine and I got the diagram in the PDF, but when changing the code (such as just removing the photon) nothing happens. It seems as if there is some problem with the rights concerning overwriting the already created diagram files. I'm not that used to ubuntu but I tried go to properties for both the files and the folder and changing to the most liberal settings - allowing both 'create and delete files' and overwriting.

Any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: You have to rerun `mf` after a change in the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you change a diagram, you have to rerun `mf` on the `simple.mf` file.

Nowadays it's much better to use `feynmp` (that requires running `mpost`) or else `feynmp-auto` that under normal usage doesn't even require running `mpost`. The syntax for diagrams is the same, just replace

```
\usepackage{feynmf}
```

with

```
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
```